# Why can't I center align my <td> text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to center the text in a dynamically produced `<td>`

I've tried all this possibilities and none of them work:

```
cell.innerHTML = "<td align=\"center\" style=\"margin-left:auto;margin-right;auto;\">&nbsp;</td>";
cell.innerHTML = "<td align=\"center\" text-align=\"center\">aaaa</td>";
cell.innerHTML = "<td style=\"text-align:center;\">aaaa</td>";
cell.innerHTML = "<td align=\"center\" text-align=\"center\">aaaa</td>";
cell.innerHTML = "<td align=\"center\">aaaa</td>";
cell.innerHTML = "<td align=\"center\" style=\"text-align:center;\">aaaa</td>";
```

Any idea of what am I missing? I can't think of more possibilities.

Well, I finally managed to solve it by simple adding a row.align="center" to the row they are added afterwards, although I thought, that tds could be aligned individually... Anyway I don't need that this time.

Comment: what is Table property ?

Comment: Might be useful if you showed some more context, an example of where you want this code to be inserted into.

Answer (score 0):

It probably is because you add a `<td>aaa</td>` to an already existing cell, so your sturcture becomes:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <td style="text-align:center">aaaa</td>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0kskmwsq/1/).

The first line adds a cell to a cell, not centering the text. The second example works, because it adds the cell to the row.

So you either have to add `td { text-align: center }` to your css, or, if you insist in using inline styles, find a way to add the cell to your row dynamically.

Comment: @Pete. You're right. I just copied and pasted it. I didn't use it in de the fiddle. I'll edit my answer.